# How to save image into sqlite database?

Tags: javascript, php, html, sqlite

I have created a php file `index.php` which used for facemask detection program in which once the user presses the button it will save locally into a desktop. My issue is how can I save it into a database and notify in `index.php`?

My `index.php` file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<h1>COVID-19 Mask Detection<h1>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.9.0/p5.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.9.0/addons/p5.dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/ml5@latest/dist/ml5.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" onclick="save()">Save Now</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
  // Classifier Variable
  let classifier;
  // Model URL
  let imageModelURL = 'https://teachablemachine.withgoogle.com/models/QLX6cenjl/';
  
  // Video
  let video;
  let flippedVideo;
  // To store the classification
  let label = "";

  // Load the model first
  function preload() {
    classifier = ml5.imageClassifier(imageModelURL + 'model.json');
  }

  function setup() {
    createCanvas(1920, 750);
    // Create the video
    video = createCapture(VIDEO);
    video.size(1920, 750);
    video.hide();

    flippedVideo = ml5.flipImage(video);
    // Start classifying
    classifyVideo();
  }
  
  function save() {
      <?php

$database = SQLITE3_OPEN_READWRITE('data.db');  

  
    
    ?>

  }
  

  function draw() {
    background(0);
    // Draw the video
    image(flippedVideo, 0, 0);

    // Draw the label
    fill(255);
    textSize(16);
    textAlign(CENTER);
    text(label, width / 2, height - 4);
  }

  // Get a prediction for the current video frame
  function classifyVideo() {
    flippedVideo = ml5.flipImage(video);
    classifier.classify(flippedVideo, gotResult);
    flippedVideo.remove();

  }

  // When we get a result
  function gotResult(error, results) {
    // If there is an error
    if (error) {
      console.error(error);
      return;
    }
    // The results are in an array ordered by confidence.
    // console.log(results[0]);
    label = results[0].label;
    // Classifiy again!
    classifyVideo();
  }
</script>
```

At `function save()` is the callback function for saving images. But now I'm stuck on how to save the image into a sqlite database.

Error Log:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function SQLITE3_OPEN_READWRITE() in C:\wamp64\www\Tester\index.php on line 80

Error: Call to undefined function SQLITE3_OPEN_READWRITE() in C:\wamp64\www\Tester\index.php on line 80
```

Comment: "How to save image into sqlite database?" Would your accept "Not at all." as an answer? I mean to not store the image in the database and instead store the path/URL to a suitable storage location. If you cannot accept that as an answer please explain what prevents you from doing so, beause I think we might be looking at a https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: @Yunnosch I've seen various online websites on how to integrate sqlite with php. But I''m confused to how to save the images into sqlite table. Coz  I don't know which is the variable to include in my sqlite __function(). Could you enlighten me on how to save it into a database?

Comment: I get the impression that the only part of my comment which you actually read is my name. This is because I get the impression that I could answer your comment by repeating my first comment verbatim.

Comment: let me modify it

Comment: You are mixing a server side language php with a client side one: js. If you want to save the images to the database you need to use Ajax

Comment: Be my guest, just [edit].

Comment: @LelioFaieta How about BLOB? Is that acceptable

Comment: You are talking about a database data type. I am talking about communication with the database

Comment: @LelioFaieta ok i'll try it out

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't store images directly in database. I assume you wanted to save it as a blob. Much better way would be to create a separate folder for images and store paths of those images in the database.